# Habilitar un elemento de un formulario (botón)

Tags: javascript

Tengo estos dos botones:

```
 <td width="58">
     <input type="button"  onclick="ejecutar('D')" name="diferencias" value="DIFERENCIAS" />
 </td>
 <td width="89">
     <input type="button"  disabled onclick="ejecutar('A')" name="ajustar" value="AJUSTAR" />
 </td>
```

Como se puede ver el de ejecutar se encuentra deshabilitado.

La idea es que sólo se habilite cuando los documentos que yo liste se encuentre en estado "D".

```
   <?php
       $sql = "SELECT
               UNIQUE(hit.c_almacen) c_almacen, d_almacen  FROM  m_almacenes al, h_inventario_teo hit WHERE hit.c_almacen = al.c_almacen AND hit.estado in('P','D')";

       p_query($sql);
       //echo "--1-<br> $sql <br><br>";
    ?>
```

lo que intente hacer es lo siguiente: cuando se ejecute la acción diferencias disables sea false

```
var rta = confirm("¿Esta seguro que desea "+acc+" el documento número "+doc+" del almacén "+alm+"?")

 if(acc=="Diferencias") {
    form1.ajustar.disabled=false;
 }else {
    form1.ajustar.disabled=true;
 }
```

De esta forma me funciona, pero ocurre que cuando tengo varios documentos y hago el proceso con 1, el botón queda habilitado. No logro hacer que el cuadro donde están los botones se actualice de acuerdo al estado.

He leído y se puede hacer algo con JavaScript, pero no logro saber en qué parte ingresarlo o como hacerlo

---

```
if (acc == "D") {
    acc = "Diferencias";
} else {
    if (acc == "A") {
        acc = "Ajustar";
    }
}
var rta = confirm("¿Esta seguro que desea " + acc + " el documento número " + doc + " del almacén " + alm + "?");
if (acc == "Diferencias") {
    form1.ajustar.disabled = false;
} else {
    form1.ajustar.disabled = true;
}
if (rta == true) {
    document.getElementById("frame111").src = "ejecutar_accion.php?accion=" + acc + "&alm‌​acen=" + alm + "&documento=" + doc;
    var contenedor2 = document.getElementById("contenedorDocumento");
    document.form1.c_almacen.value = 0;
    contenedor2.innerHTML = "";
} else {
    form1.ajustar.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: en el html de ejemplo defines un unico boton, como sera cuando tienes varios documentos ? en que contexto estaria el html de esos botones o como diferencias uno de otro. No puede usar jquery?

Comment: podrias editar la pregunta y poner el codigo alli, porque como comentarios no se entiende

Comment: @NorbeyMartinez Si alguna de las respuestas solucionó tu problema, por favor considerá aceptarla haciendo click en el **✓** a la izquierda de la misma (ambos se benefician). Más información en **[¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. También tené en cuenta votar +1 (flecha hacia arriba) a todas las que te resultaron útiles.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes lograrlo así:

```js
//Aqui se le agrega la funcionalidad en el evento click a todos
//Los botones que tengan la clase **btn**
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
 
 //En este caso esta simulado el valor de la variable **acc**
 //Aquí tendrías que obtener el valor para después compararlo 
 //y decidir si se inhabilita o no
 var acc="Diferencias";

 //this hace referencia al botón al cual se le dio click
 if(acc=="Diferencias") {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
 }else {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
 }

});

//Si al final por ejemplo quieres inhabilitar todos los botones quedaría así:
//Inhabilitando todos los botones con la clase **btn**
//$(".btn").prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<-- Se le agrega la clase btn a todos los botones que quieres que compartan
La misma funcionalidad !-->
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Boton">
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberás de colocarle algún **ID** a tus botones para identificarlos

```
 <td width="58">
     <input type="button" id="boton1" onclick="ejecutar('D')" name="diferencias" value="DIFERENCIAS" />
 </td>
 <td width="89">
     <input type="button" id="boton2" disabled onclick="ejecutar('A')" name="ajustar" value="AJUSTAR" />
 </td>
```

Luego en javascript haces referencia a cada boton por medio del ID y los asignas a una variable:

```
var boton1 = document.getElementById("boton1");
var boton1 = document.getElementById("boton2");
```

Para habilitarlos o deshabilitarlos solo asignas el valor de la propiedad **disabled** en la variable que antes asignaste:

```
boton1.disabled = true;
boton1.disabled = false;
```

Si vas a usar jquery tenés que mandar a colocar y quitar el atributo **disabled** del control, pero siempre utilizando los **ID**

Por ejemplo para deshabilitar el boton:

```
$("#boton1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Y para volverlo a habilitar:

```
$("#boton1").removeAttr("disabled");
```